# httpd overwrite conf file directive with conf.d directive

Tags: httpd, httpd.conf

I am quite new to Apache configuration (working with [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com)).

In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` there is this directive:

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

# Enable server-status for internal IP
<Location /server-status>
   SetHandler server-status
   Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

It's working and throwing 403 error, when visiting http://example.com/server-status

Now I want to add my own IP address without actually changing this file, so I use `/etc/httpd/conf.d/customRules.conf` (`11.234.567.789` is actual my IP)

```
# Enable server-status for internal IP
<Location /server-status>
   SetHandler server-status
   Require ip 127.0.0.1 11.234.567.789
</Location>
```

But I still receive `403` error like it's not working.

How to overwrite directive from `conf/httpd.conf` in `conf.d/customRules.conf`?

Comment: /server-info may help.  It will give you the final configuration after all the imports.  Also verify the access log to see if your IP address has been modified by a proxy or by a NAT rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the line reading `Include conf.d/*.conf` (or `IncludeOptional`) in `httpd.conf` comes *after* the `Location` block, otherwise your own config will be overwritten again.

Yes, it might be necessary to alter `httpd.conf`  in this case - you can't avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked moving `Include` to the end of file (can this have negative impact?)